# How to get the symbol for the Bangladesh currency (taka)? ৳

Tags: symbols, currency

I tried to just copy paste the symbol ৳, but this resulted in an error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you try the `currency` package: https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/currency/currency_doc.pdf with `BDT` as ISO-Code?

Comment: You need to have a font that has that character. If you are using pdftex this will need to be in some legacy 8bit encoding, there will be few (if any) fonts suitable. If you are using lualatex or xelatex then as llong as you are using a font that supports this script you should be able to use the character directly with no problems.

Comment: If you are asking about an error don't just say "resulted in an error" show the exact error from the log file, in a `{}` code section in the question.